# How to set constraint on stackview

Tags: swift, uibutton, uistackview

I'm having some button that can move upward and downward in the stack view. However, when I set the stack view constraint, the button move upward then cannot recognise any click.

I have tried to not set the stack view constraint. But the whole stack view will on the top of the screen.

```
@IBAction func cardButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print(sender.tag)

    switch sender.tag {
    case 1:
        if clickOrNot == false {
            pockerButton1.frame.origin.y -= 50
            print(clickOrNot)
        } else {
            pockerButton1.frame.origin.y += 50
        }
        clickOrNot.toggle()
    default:
        break
    }

}
```

I expect the whole stack view can be constrained and the button sill work fine.

Comment: Hi, Can you attach storyboard Screenshots and Constraints? Its very hard to tell...

Comment: `UIStackView` ***arranges*** its subviews, so you don't want to be trying to change the frame origin. What are you really trying to do? Do you have multiple subviews in the stack view, and you want to re-arrange them?